# Is it possible to use Jupyter Notebook in Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-shell

What I have tried:

Start Google Cloud shell

```
sudo pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Add the following to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = 'localhost'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8080
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.ConnectionFileMixin.control_port = 8081
c.ConnectionFileMixin.hb_port = 8082
c.ConnectionFileMixin.iopub_port = 8083
c.ConnectionFileMixin.shell_port = 8084
c.ConnectionFileMixin.stdin_port = 0
```

Run

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --debug
```

Go to web preview, the home page loads just fine, but when I load a new notebook .ipynb, I get:

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The
>   notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network
>   connection or notebook server configuration.

Error in developer console:

> main.min.js:22712 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://8080-dot-2103947-dot-devshell.appspot.com/api/kernels/05832e24-2cd6-421c-aa55-16c58eceab94/channels?session_id=83EE7CD1C17942BE827623E5DFF08240'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   400

But in Google Cloud Shell, there is no 400 error:

```
[D 19:36:27.820 NotebookApp] Searching [u'/home/jie', '/home/jie/.jupyter', '/usr/etc/jupyter', '/usr/local/etc/jupyter', '/etc/jupyter'] for config files
[D 19:36:27.821 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.822 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.861 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /usr/etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.862 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /home/jie/.jupyter
[D 19:36:27.863 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_config in /home/jie
[D 19:36:27.865 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.866 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /usr/local/etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.866 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /usr/etc/jupyter
[D 19:36:27.867 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /home/jie/.jupyter
[D 19:36:27.868 NotebookApp] Loaded config file: /home/jie/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
[D 19:36:27.869 NotebookApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in /home/jie
[I 19:36:29.267 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jie
[I 19:36:29.268 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 19:36:29.268 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8080/
[I 19:36:29.268 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 19:36:36.858 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?authuser=0 (127.0.0.1) 1.20ms
[D 19:36:37.525 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 19:36:37.562 NotebookApp] 200 GET /tree (::1) 38.02ms
[D 19:36:38.268 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.css (127.0.0.1) 1.60ms
[D 19:36:39.180 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/services/contents.js?v=20160919193627 (::1) 1.45ms
[D 19:36:39.184 NotebookApp] 200 GET /custom/custom.js?v=20160919193627 (127.0.0.1) 1.47ms
[D 19:36:39.906 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/tree?_=1474285000896 (::1) 3.61ms
[D 19:36:39.910 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000900 (127.0.0.1) 1.15ms
[D 19:36:39.915 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?_=1474285000897 (::1) 3.59ms
[D 19:36:39.918 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000898 (::1) 1.07ms
[D 19:36:39.940 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000899 (127.0.0.1) 20.56ms
[D 19:36:39.945 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:36:39.945 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:36:39.947 NotebookApp] 304 GET /api/kernelspecs (127.0.0.1) 5.75ms
[D 19:36:40.593 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000901 (::1) 4.76ms
[D 19:37:40.160 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000902 (127.0.0.1) 1.15ms
[D 19:37:40.162 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000903 (::1) 0.65ms
[D 19:37:41.392 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000904 (127.0.0.1) 3.10ms
[D 19:38:40.143 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000905 (::1) 1.34ms
[D 19:38:40.209 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000906 (127.0.0.1) 1.07ms
[D 19:38:40.766 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000907 (::1) 3.33ms
[D 19:39:14.165 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000908 (127.0.0.1) 1.05ms
[D 19:39:14.192 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000909 (::1) 0.96ms
[D 19:39:14.761 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000910 (127.0.0.1) 3.22ms
[D 19:40:40.338 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000911 (::1) 1.40ms
[D 19:40:40.363 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000912 (127.0.0.1) 0.94ms
[D 19:40:40.936 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000913 (::1) 3.39ms
[D 19:42:13.646 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000914 (127.0.0.1) 1.41ms
[D 19:42:13.649 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000915 (::1) 0.77ms
[D 19:42:15.178 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000916 (127.0.0.1) 5.44ms
[I 19:42:17.736 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in 
[D 19:42:17.738 NotebookApp] Saving /home/jie/Untitled1.ipynb
[D 19:42:17.851 NotebookApp] 201 POST /api/contents (::1) 117.08ms
[D 19:42:18.462 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 19:42:18.494 NotebookApp] 200 GET /notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python2 (127.0.0.1) 32.79ms
[D 19:42:19.275 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.css (::1) 1.28ms
[D 19:42:19.296 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full,Safe&delayStartupUntil=configured (127.0.0.1) 2.40ms
[D 19:42:20.407 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/TeX-AMS_HTML-full.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 2.29ms
[D 19:42:20.609 NotebookApp] 304 GET /custom/custom.js?v=20160919193627 (127.0.0.1) 1.11ms
[D 19:42:21.246 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/common?_=1474285342417 (::1) 3.12ms
[D 19:42:21.300 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1474285342418 (127.0.0.1) 44.64ms
[D 19:42:21.302 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:42:21.303 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:42:21.305 NotebookApp] 304 GET /api/kernelspecs (127.0.0.1) 2.81ms
[D 19:42:21.309 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/config/notebook?_=1474285342416 (::1) 2.74ms
[D 19:42:22.147 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:42:22.149 NotebookApp] Starting kernel: ['/usr/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel', '-f', u'/home/jie/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-05832e24-2cd6-421c-aa55-16c58eceab94.json']
[D 19:36:37.562 NotebookApp] 200 GET /tree (::1) 38.02ms
[D 19:42:22.153 NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:8081
[I 19:42:22.155 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 05832e24-2cd6-421c-aa55-16c58eceab94
[D 19:42:22.155 NotebookApp] Kernel args: {'kernel_name': u'python2', 'cwd': u'/home/jie'}
[D 19:42:22.161 NotebookApp] 201 POST /api/sessions (::1) 87.33ms
[D 19:42:22.165 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb/checkpoints?_=1474285342419 (127.0.0.1) 1.60ms
[D 19:42:22.276 NotebookApp] Using contents: services/contents
[W 19:42:22.293 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20160919193627 (::1) 19.36ms referer=https://8080-dot-2103947-dot-devshell.appspot
.com/notebooks/Untitled1.ipynb?kernel_name=python2
[D 19:42:22.350 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) available from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:42:22.351 NotebookApp] Serving kernel resource from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
[D 19:42:22.356 NotebookApp] 304 GET /kernelspecs/python2/logo-64x64.png (127.0.0.1) 7.08ms
[D 19:42:22.401 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/style/style.min.css.map (::1) 1.83ms
[D 19:42:22.549 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?rev=2.6.0 (127.0.0.1) 2.08ms
[D 19:42:23.217 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX-Web/fontdata.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 1.41ms
[D 19:42:23.240 NotebookApp] 200 GET /static/components/MathJax/extensions/Safe.js?rev=2.6.0 (127.0.0.1) 1.25ms
[D 19:42:52.652 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?_=1474285000917 (::1) 3.00ms
[D 19:42:52.654 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/terminals?_=1474285000918 (127.0.0.1) 0.65ms
[D 19:42:53.314 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1474285000919 (::1) 4.03ms
[D 19:44:22.156 NotebookApp] 200 GET /api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb?content=0&_=1474285342420 (127.0.0.1) 1.36ms
[I 19:44:22.762 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled1.ipynb
[D 19:44:22.763 NotebookApp] Saving /home/jie/Untitled1.ipynb
[D 19:44:22.826 NotebookApp] 200 PUT /api/contents/Untitled1.ipynb (::1) 64.32ms
```

So that leads me to think the web socket requests didn't reach the kernel, they were blocked by Google Cloud Shell. Google App Engine does not provide Socket API for free, is this the reason why I can't get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Google Cloud Shell is not meant to stand up a web socket service and is not configured for that. In addition, there are service limits that you'll likely hit if you try to do this, check the Usage Limits and Outgoing Connections sections [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations)

Check out Google Compute Engine and Google Container Engine for this purpose, both are not free past the trial though.

Answer (score -1):

how to deploy jupiter server on cloud shell

paste 1 by one commands to deploy jupiter server on google cloud shell for free

for vedio toutorial goto here https://rumble.com/v45v132-jupyter-lab-deploy-on-cloud-shell.html

1: docker pull ubuntu:latest

2: docker run -it --name my-ubuntu ubuntu

3====

apt-get update && \

apt-get install -y \

software-properties-common \

curl \

wget \

&& apt-get clean \

&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

4===

apt-get update && \

apt-get install -y \

python3 \

python3-pip \

&& apt-get clean \

&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

5: apt update

6: apt install nano -y

7: python3 -m pip install notebook

8: python3 -m notebook --version

9: jupyter notebook --generate-config

10: nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

11: c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True

#then press ctrl+x and y then hit enter

12: ====

wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.tgz

tar -xvf ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.tgz

13: ./ngrok authtoken your_auth_token

14: pip3 install notebook

15: python3 -m notebook --allow-root

16: docker ps -a

## copy or note your contaner id

17: docker exec -it 85525721994a /bin/bash 17

#for example my contaner id is 85525721994a

## <^^^^^^^^^^^> paste your contaner id

18: ./ngrok http 8888